# How to configure a different font size for the diff view in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: fonts, intellij-idea

I did not find a way to configure the font size in the diff view in IntelliJ IDEA (this view is shown when we compare two files). It is possible to change the font size temporarily for the currently compared files, as described [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/zooming-in-the-editor.html), but it's not possible to set a different font as the default font to be used in each new diff view. 
Do you know how to do it? Or is it impossible? I'm using the version 13 of IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that's not possible. You can change the font size for *all* editors (`IDE Settings` - `Editor` - `Colors & Fonts` - `Font`) and you can change the *colors* for your diff view (
`IDE Settings` - `Editor` - `Colors & Fonts` - `Diff`), but you cannot change the *font size* for the diff view.